# Why is my facebook messenger chatbot not working with messenger lite application?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, chatbot, facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot, facebook-chatbot

I am developing a Facebook Messenger chatbot using Node.js and Facebook Graph API. Everything works fine with the normal **Messenger** application until I test it using the **Messenger Lite** application. No **get started** button, no **persistent menu**, no **quick replies**, and **cards** of generic template are not shown correctly.

Why is the Messenger Lite application not supporting those features? And, Is there any way to make the chatbot works on the Messenger Lite application correctly, as it is in the normal Messenger application?

Comment: _"Why is the Messenger Lite application not supporting those features?"_ - what would be the point of a "lite" version, if it covered the whole functionality of the "full" one.

Comment: Yes, you are right! Is there any way to detect if the user of the chatbot is using normal Messenger or Messenger Lite ? @CBroe